# SAS Enterprise Guide export as step in process path selection

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

As part of the SAS Enterprise Guide export as a step in process the outhput file location is very tedious to select. Is there any faster way to do it than clicking through all the folders on my harddrive for every export.
The path is shown but I am not able to edit the path or paste a path here:

[image]

And when i press browse I am still not able to paste a path:
[image]

Am I doing something wrong, missing a setting or is there some kind of workaround.

Temporary question to Joe:
Like this?
[image]

Comment: What exactly are you exporting? If tables, is there a reason why you are using export as step in process? Because using a macro should be way faster. Even using proc export every time should be faster. You can paste the path there after all.

Comment: Yes I am exporting tables to excel in a location on the harddrive. 
How would you use a macro to export I only know about proc export, but I usually get issues with the formatting when I use that.

Comment: Well, you have to write a macro that is using proc export with features that you need. In your case with fixes for your formatting issues. A benefit of using a macro over proc export  by itself is that you can easily export every table you want at once.

Comment: Can you show me an example of a macro export you have done yourself?

Comment: Macro I'm using is kinda complicated and probably too long(dozens of pages) for your use, as it makes the tables and then export them. And even isolating the exporting part is a pain, as it firstly creates an .xls file, and then fill it up sheet by sheet (firstly values, then standard error, then few other things).

Comment: What version of Enterprise Guide are you using??

Comment: @Joe I use SAS EG version 8.3

Comment: @Negdo Okay but it is nice to know how it can be expanded thank you for the inspiration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the most basic example of a macro, that can export your tables as excel files:

```
%macro ExportExcel(path,file_name,tab_name);
proc export data=&tab_name
    outfile="&path.&file_name..xlsx"
    dbms=xlsx
    replace;
run;
%mend;
```

You can just paste your path, or better yet, make it a macro variable using %let statement.

But depending on your needs you can make this macro way more complicated. You can put more than one table into a single .xlsx file on different sheets, using a sheet statement. You can export every table from a whole library. It really depends on what you want.

Comment: Do you have an example of one with more exports?

Comment: What do you mean with more exports? Be specific. Mind you, you don't actually need to change this macro to export numerous tables. You can use call execute statement for example.

Comment: That's not really consistent with this question, you'd want to ask another question if this is the direction you're going and you want to know how to use this.

Comment: I was just refering to this "You can put more than one table into a single .xlsx file on different sheets, using a sheet statement. You can export every table from a whole library. It really depends on what you want."
I was hoping you had an example of this on hand becuase it sounds quite usefull even tough it wasn't what I was asking for in the original question

Comment: Sheet statement will save your table into a specific excel sheet. So if you have multiple tables saved into the same .xlsx file, with different sheet statements, you will get one file which contains multiple tables. Exporting every table from a whole library would require to include a loop into a macro, and go trough every memname with a certain libname from dictionary.tables. But for details you should really open another question.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to paste a full path into the filename box, just as with any other "save" dialog.  This certainly works with the current version (Enterprise Guide 8.3), but should work with older versions as well.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work for me. I cannot edit the address at all. I have to go to browse, and then select it folder by folder.

Comment: It didn't work for me I posted a screenshot of how I did it in the buttom of my question. Am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an EG 7 install anymore.  Strongly recommend you upgrade to EG 8, it definitely supports what I describe.  It's about 3 years old now, so long past time to upgrade.

Comment: I actually have SAS EG version 8.3 the newest version is 9.4

Comment: SAS EG 8.3 is the newest version (https://support.sas.com/en/software/enterprise-guide-support.html); you're confusing EG with SAS version.    If you have 8.3, though, you should definitely be able to do what I just suggested - I did it myself yesterday.